# Symfony Custom Validation Constraint pass parameter

Tags: validation, symfony, constraints, unique-constraint

I have a custom validation constraint to check if an entered book name in a form is unique.
I cannot use @Unique, because that would also validate the current value of the book and will always throw a validation error, even if I didn't want to change the book name.

(If there is a way to ignore the current value, I would love to hear it, but still I'd like to know how to pass a custom object to a custom validator :) )

So I wrote this for the name property of the book entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity("name", groups={"Creation"})
 */
 public class Book {

  /* 
  * @var string
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique = true)
  * @CustomAssert\UniqueBookName(groups={"Editmode"})
  */
  protected $name;

 }
```

For that to work, I need the current book name that I want to validate in the UniqueBookName Validator class.

How can I **pass now the current book name to my validator class** in this line:

```
@CustomAssert\UniqueBookName(groups={"Editmode"})
```

I know how to pass parameters in here with:

```
 @CustomAssert\UniqueBookName(exampleProperty="name", groups={"Editmode"})
```

but how can I pass as e.g. exampleProperty the **real value** of the current book name, not the string "name"?

Regards

---

Update for answer:

My Class Constraint:

```
 /**
 *@CustomAssert\UniqueBookName(nameProperty="name", groups={"Editmode"})
 */
 class Book{
  // Property as you described
 }
```

My Validator classes:

```
class UniqueBookName extends Constraint{

 public $message = 'book.edit.name';
 public $nameProperty;

 public function getDefaultOption()
 {
     return 'nameProperty';
 }

 public function getRequiredOptions()
 {
     return array('nameProperty');
 }

 public function validatedBy()
 {
     return 'bookName_validator';
 }


 public function getTargets()
 {
     return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
 }

}
```

And the corresponding validators "validate"-Method:

```
 public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
  {
   // here, in $constraint I only see the String Value "name", not the current value I want.
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to attach the a virtual resource to the form as a way to accomplish these kinds of validations.

When you construct your Book model, simply assign it a new property with an instance of the book record. Then, you can apply your validator as a class constraint (instead of property based) so you can have access to the entire model.

```
$book = new Book(); 
$book->oldBook = $repository->fetchBook($id); 
$form ...
```

As a good practice to make this model as reusable as possible, I additionally specify the properties names as parameters to the constraint. Using [property accessor](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html), you can then retrieve the values. Almost exactly like the UniqueEntity class validator is specifying "name" property.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @CustomAssert\UniqueBookName(bookProperty="oldBook", bookNameProperty="name", groups={"Editmode"})
 * @UniqueEntity("name", groups={"Creation"})
 */
 public class Book {

  /* 
  * @var string
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique = true)
  */
  protected $name;

 }
```

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your answer. I created the class constraint and for testing I only wanted to pass the current nameProperty, so no "whole book". The problem I get is that within the "bookNameProperty", I just see the string "name", but not the actual name value. I update my question with my current code, maybe you can have a look at it :)

Comment: The value "name" is the property path to your model. Please read the link I posted above called property accessor. You pass this path and your model to the accessor, and it will return the value for you.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry :) I'll have a look, thanks! I tried one hour to figure out how the "UniqueEntity" constraint works, so I think property accessors should be the solution.

Comment: I don't understand how this should work John. I always end up by having plain Strings within my validate() Method. From within my FormHandler, i call: $errors = $this->validator->validate($book, array('Default', 'Editmode')); Before that, I added the new "oldBook" to the $book. I also installed via composer the property accessor, but within my validate() Method, I don't have access to the $book.

Comment: I followed along this example:
https://gist.github.com/stof/d21838b00d08858ae6bb

But still, calling "$constraint->bookProperty" - bookProperty is a string of "oldBook" ..

Comment: Ah now i get the Book Object in $value :) Now is the question - how can i get the value that the user entered ? Normally, it would be stored in $value, but now, $value is the current $book-object. Shall i create a new "temporary" property called "newBookName" within my Book Entity?

Comment: Works like a charm now, thanks for your help. The link I posted was also very useful.

Comment: If you are applying it as a class constraint, you have access to the entire model. $value in your case IS the model.